# Recommended way to type a function with long signature, TS

Tags: typescript

I have a type of this kind:

```
type FType = (a:Hello, b:string[] c: Naughty[]) => MyType
```

Would like to be assigned to a function:

```
function myNiceFn(a,b,c){
```

But this seems bad:

```
const myNiceFn: FType = myNiceFn(...){
```

I read the docs, and nothing seems good enough.

And anonymous functions there would be bad for traceback errors.

What is the best way to do it?

Comment: "*But this seems bad:*" because it's syntactically invalid? Or is it supposed to be valid code? If it's the latter, then what is bad about it?

Comment: *"But this seems bad"* In what way? Can you be more specific? If you fix the basic syntax errors, [it works](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAEhA28D2UC8UDeUAeAuKAzsAE4CWAdgOYDcUAvtQFCiRQByAhgK6UAWoaTFBD4iZKrQbNw0ALIgAKjMFYAXqJIUa9JtNYAxJa3QAKDrjiIkAGigAjDeMoBtALq2Axvk49+INwCUaAB8UPJGEIyMHkjkRFAAtiBspB4Q+uT4hsqmHLZ2nkGooRiMUOVQxBDAXMTkmOpQHAB02FAA1PbOAAyuHVAePa7NIFIMQA). ([Arrow function syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).)

Comment: Are you asking how to apply that type to a traditional function (one using the `function` keyword) instead of an arrow function?

Comment: Side note: That isn't a particularly long function signature. :-) (But that doesn't mean there aren't reasons for having and using a function type -- for instance, callbacks.)

Comment: @VLAZ too many words

Answer (score 0):

> But this seems bad:
>
> ```typescript
> const myNiceFn: FType = myNiceFn(...){
> ```

In a comment you've said you mean it's "too many words," but it's slightly more concise with the correct syntax:

```typescript
const myNiceFn: FType = (a, b, c) => {
    // ...
};
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAEhA28D2UC8UDeUAeAuKAzsAE4CWAdgOYDcUAvtQFCiRQByAhgK6UAWoaTFBD4iZKrQbNw0ALIgAKjMFYAXqJIUa9JtNYAxJa3QAKDrjiIkAGigAjDeMoBtALq2Axvk49+INwCUaAB8UPJGEIyMHkjkRFAAtiBspB4Q+uT4hsqmHLZ2nkGooRiMUOVQxBDAXMTkmOpQHAB02FAA1PbOAAyuHVAePa7NIFIMQA)

It's not going to get much more concise than that with a separately-declared function type. All of those parts are necessary:

- `const` (or `let`) to start a declaration
- The name of the constant/variable
- The type
- The function definition

Notice that there's no need to provide the types of the parameters, or the return type; that's what `FType` does.

---

Just for completeness for future readers, although it doesn't relate to your "too many words" issue:

If for some reason you needed to use `FType` on a traditional (`function`) function, you can just do the same thing with a traditional function expression:

```typescript
const myNiceFn: FType = function(a, b, c) {
    // ...
};
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAEhA28D2UC8UDeUAeAuKAzsAE4CWAdgOYDcUAvtQFCiRQByAhgK6UAWoaTFBD4iZKrQbNw0ALIgAKjMFYAXqJIUa9JtNYAxJa3QAKDrjiIkAGigAjDeMoBtALq2Axvk49+INwCUaAB8UPJGEIyMHkjkRFAAtiBspB4Q+uT4hsroAGZc5B7ApLFmtnaeQRiMULVQxBDAXMTkmOpQHAB02FAA1PbOAAyufVAeQ66dIFJSQA)

If you wanted to use a function *declaration*, you can't directly use `FType` to set its type. Usually there's no need to use a function declaration instead of a function expression, but if you have an unusual situation, you can at least use the types from `FType` using `Parameters` (for a tuple of the parameter types) and `ReturnType` (for the return type):

```typescript
function myNiceFn(...args: Parameters<FType>): ReturnType<FType> {
    const [a, b, c] = args;
    return {z: a.x + b[0] + c[0].y};
}
```

TypeScript even provides hints for the parameters nicely, despite it being a rest parameter.

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAEhA28D2UC8UDeUAeAuKAzsAE4CWAdgOYDcUAvtQFCiRQByAhgK6UAWoaTFBD4iZKrQbNw0ALIgAKjMFYAXqJIUa9JtNYAxJa3QAKDrjiIkAGigAjDeMoBtALq2Axvk49+INwCUaAB8UPJGEIyMAGZc5B7ApEjkUAC2IGykHhD65CYAdIUcxJQE+AAKxRypEMAQxAQAPIYywQH4AEq1XMTkEc0RoRiMUKNQHslEUM4ctnaeroLFpUxjUMTdvZjqUBz52FAA1PbOAAyLxx5nrvkgUnSMQA)

Comment: my post clearly states that anonymous functions aren't useful here, because they mess up the traceback errors, as they won't have a name.